# Recursively concat columns in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, concatenation, recursive-query

I have a table containing values as follows

```
╔═══╦════╦════╦══════╦══════╗
║ b ║ l1 ║ l2 ║  l3  ║  l4  ║
╠═══╬════╬════╬══════╬══════╣
║ a ║ b1 ║ c1 ║  d1  ║  e1  ║
║ d ║ x1 ║ y1 ║ null ║ null ║
╚═══╩════╩════╩══════╩══════╝
```

The output should be:

```
╔═══════════╗
║ ab1c1d1e1 ║
║ ab1c1d1   ║
║ ab1c1     ║
║ ab1       ║
║ dx1y1     ║
║ dx1       ║
╚═══════════╝
```

Is it possible? I see a pattern here but able to figure it out how to do it.
P.S: ROLLUP can't be used as the server doesn't support it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT * FROM(
    SELECT  b + l1 + l2 + l3 + l4 FROM tbl UNION ALL
    SELECT  b + l1 + l2 + l3 FROM tbl UNION ALL
    SELECT  b + l1 + l2 FROM tbl UNION ALL
    SELECT  b + l1 FROM tbl
) AS t(a)
WHERE a IS NOT NULL
```

Execution plan:

[image]

---

Here is another way to `UNPIVOT`, this will scan the table only once:

```
SELECT x.a
FROM tbl t
CROSS APPLY(VALUES
    (b + l1 + l2 + l3 + l4),
    (b + l1 + l2 + l3),
    (b + l1 + l2),
    (b + l1)
) AS x(a)
WHERE a IS NOT NULL
```

Execution plan:

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a way of doing this without hard-coding the columns and rows to `SELECT` (I starred this question, by the way).

Comment: It scans the table everytime the select is done. And since its an xml in the back. Its going to be expensive. I need to get the output in say 3 to 5 ms to the max.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, dynamic SQL maybe.

Comment: @TejalKarande, I don't think there is a faster way. The other solution will involve having to `UNPIVOT` each row and then `JOIN` which I believe would be more expensive. I'll leave it for you to test.

Comment: @TejalKarande, see my `CROSS APPLY` version. I believe it'll be faster than the `UNION ALL`

Comment: I have tried UNPIVOT too. but its taking 30 to 100ms depending on the load on the server. So thats out.

Comment: Well, the display itself is gonna take time. Still, I believe the `CROSS APPLY` would be the fastest method

Comment: Till I dont get another alternative, will use CROSS APPLY . Thanks :)

Comment: hi there! going for the union all solution, reason : the (estimated) number of rows returned by the cross apply query are too much thus Sql server decides to bring almost all the rows from the master table with which I am joining this table, whereas the previous query enables it to estimate the #rows of the xml.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: This enhanced solution delivers the data as naked strings. If this is fast - I don't know. Please let me know...

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE( b varchar(100),l1 varchar(100),l2 varchar(100),l3 varchar(100), l4 varchar(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('a','b1','c1','d1','e1')
,('d','x1','y1',null,null);


SELECT u.v.value('.','varchar(max)')
FROM
(
    SELECT   '' + b + l1 + l2 + l3 + l4 + ';' AS x
            ,'' + b + l1 + l2 + l3 + ';'      AS x
            ,'' + b + l1 + l2 + ';'           AS x
            ,'' + b + l1 + ';'                AS x
    FROM @tbl
    FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
) AS XMLList(x)
CROSS APPLY XMLList.x.nodes('/x') AS a(b) 
CROSS APPLY(SELECT CAST('<r>' + REPLACE(a.b.value('.','varchar(max)'),';','</r><r>') + '</r>' AS XML)) AS m(n)
CROSS APPLY m.n.nodes('/r') AS u(v)
WHERE LEN(u.v.value('.','varchar(max)'))> 0

/* Result

ab1c1d1e1
ab1c1d1
ab1c1
ab1
dx1y1
dx1

*/
```

Comment: Hey if I am inserting the xml in a table the table creation itself takes time so thats not an option. Thanks :)

Comment: @TejalKarande, you find an enhanced variation in my answer. The result is no XML anymore, but - to be honest - I do not expect this to be faster than Felix' answer. I'd just be curious if this works...

Comment: Hey.. when I am comparing it with cross apply, your query is slower.. Thanks :)